# How to use existing PDF file with PrintedPdfDocument?

Tags: java, android, pdf

Is there a way to open an existing PDF file with some template and continue drawing on it?

I'm using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument but it only works with new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Android SDK that allows you to modify existing PDF files for any purpose, let alone printing. You will need to look at third-party libraries for that (e.g., iText).